# CSS not being applied

Tags: css

I am pretty new to web design, so this is a perplexing problem to me. I am creating a floating social media share button to the left of my content that scrolls with the blog content. Here is the code I am using:

```
<div id="floating-menu-blog" style="opacity:0.3;filter:alpha(opacity=30)"
onmouseover="this.style.opacity=1;this.filters.alpha.opacity=100"
onmouseout="this.style.opacity=0.3;this.filters.alpha.opacity=30">

<div class="float-title">
<iframe src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets/tweet_button.html?url=<?php echo      rawurlencode(get_permalink()) ?>&amp;text=<?php echo  rawurlencode(strip_tags(get_the_title())) ?>&amp;count=vertical" style="width:55px;  height:62px;" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>


<div class="float-title">
<script type="text/javascript">var fbShare = {
url: <?php the_permalink() ?>,
size: 'large',
badge_text: 'fff',
badge_color: '3b5998',
google_analytics: 'true'
}</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://widgets.fbshare.me/files/fbshare.js">      </script>
```

And here is what is in my css file:

```
/*float social media buttons*/
#floating-menu-blog {background-color:#fff;border:1px solid #ccc;position: fixed; left: 50%; top: 342px; margin-left:-554px; z-index:100;}
#floating-menu .float-title{padding:1px 3px;}
#floating-menu .float-title a{color:#000;text-decoration:none}
```

However, on the site, the css is not being applied at all. I cleared all caches and disabled w3total cache to make sure that wasn't the issue. I have no clue what the issue is as it was working a week ago and I really haven't changed anything in relation to this code.

Please let me know if I can provide more info. Thanks!

Comment: what is the browser seeing? have you installed firebug in firefox to check what CSS files are actually loading?

Comment: Screenshots would also be VERY helpful. As Mild Fuzz said, Firebug is a great place to start.

Comment: Also, I would use the :hover meta parameter instead of the onmouseover/onmouseout stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I figured it out. Basically, it was a plugin conflicting with the last portion of my css files. I appreciate the help. As for John Bloch, go ahead and answer my questions if you want to see the acceptance rate go up: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8307/admin-password-keeps-changing (not answered), http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7296/categories-assigned-to-custom-post-type-not-found (not answered), and my other two questions were asked before the accept an answer option was available. Just responding to a douche response with a douche answer

Comment: @Jeff Since I was one of the first dozen people to join the WordPress Answers project in Area 51, and have been active ever since, believe me when I say that there has ALWAYS been an 'Accept Answer' option. In fact, it's one of the few things you can do with only 1 reputation. I looked at your questions and their answers before commenting and wouldn't have said that if I didn't see multiple questions that should have been accepted. Glad to see you went back and accepted the ones that did have good answers, though. :)

Comment: @Jeff as for the 'douche' factor, it's in the best interest of the community for questions to have accepted answers wherever possible. What I said wasn't anything personal.

Comment: @Jeff if you had figured out your issue please add solution as answer and accept it so this question doesn't haunt us all :) TIA

Comment: Thanks for the info, John. I didn't mean to come off so harsh, just in a bad mood after spending so much time trying to figure that issue out. I will include the answer to this question and accept - didn't know I could do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A plugin conflicted witt eh last 30 lines or so of my css file. No idea what exactly it did to cause this, but disabled the plugin and everything is solved.